# Растягивание всех <ul> <li> по всему блоку навигации

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Не могу выровнять элементы навигации по ширине блока.
Использую свойство flex. Проблема в последнем элементе, который имеет отступ справа, чего быть не должно.
Помогите понять в чем причина. Спасибо.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: #2D7DC1;
  font-size: 17px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #325BAA;
}

.nav__inner {
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.menu__item {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: opacity .1s linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav__inner">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu__item">Главная</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu__item">Услуги</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu__item">Документы</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu__item">Наши работы</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu__item">Галерея</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu__item">Контакты</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: #2D7DC1;
    font-size: 17px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    padding: 20px 0;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #325BAA;
}

.menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu__item {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition: opacity .1s linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu__item">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu__item">Услуги</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu__item">Документы</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu__item">Наши работы</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu__item">Галерея</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu__item">Контакты</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```